# delete files in multiple subfolders with batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I have a directory that looks like this

> "C:\sales\client1\file1".

The client1 folder it's not static and can vary from client1 to client100 and each file inside the client folder can vary from file1 to file8.

I want to delete 4 speciefic files (eg file1, file3, file6 and file8) in every client folder, based on a mask (/m file1*) older than 7 days (d-7) using a batch.

So far every solution i have tried works for a specified directory

Thank you

Comment: [SO] isn't a script writing service, what have you tried so far? [edit] your question to conntain your efforts in a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, if you noticed i said that every solution i tried worked only for a given path, my problem is changing subfolder without having to add a line for every folder.

Comment: This site expects you to provide the code you've tried which is causing the issue you're reporting. If you've tried more than one solution, it is important that you post those attempts and explain exactly what happens, which differs from yuor expectaitions, when you run each.

Answer (score 1):

As your mask is a file and the `@path` will contain the file name,

you'll have to cd to the folder with `\..` appended to it `@path\..`

So try:

```
 forfiles /P C:\Sales /S /M file1* /D -7 /C "cmd.exe /c @cd /D @path\..&del file1 file3 file6 file8"
```

This command will also find file1 matching the criteria directly in `C:\Sales`

A more consize solution using PowerShell

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Sales\Client*\file1" -File | 
  Where LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-7)| 
    ForEach-Object {
      PushD $_.Directory
      Remove-Object file[1368]
      PopD
    }
```